# SpringBoard header errors when compiling tweaks with theos

Tags: ios, jailbreak, tweak, theos

I am new to `jailbreak` `tweaks` development and I am using theos to develop my tweaks but I ran into some issues when I was compiling my tweak with the make command.

Basically I dumped all the `IOS 7 SpringBoard` headers with class-dump-z and placed all of them in the theos/include folder. I realize that there's a class called `XXUnknownSuperClass` and when I was compiling the tweak I got some error from that class.

```
/theos/include/Spring/SBUIAnimationController.h:8:9: error: 
      'XXUnknownSuperclass.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes"
      instead
#import <XXUnknownSuperclass.h> // Unknown library
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        "XXUnknownSuperclass.h"

/theos/include/Spring/XXUnknownSuperclass.h:14:12: error: 
      cannot find interface declaration for 'XXUnknownSuperclass'
@interface XXUnknownSuperclass (SBApplicationAdditions)

fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
```

And the next question that I have is can I hook the `SBIconViewDelegate` to run custom method when the app icons on the `SpringBoard` is tapped?

Thanks a lot for your helps!

Answer (score 0):

Some of the header files from class dump can not be used directly. There are some common errors and could be changed as below.

```
#import "NSObject.h"
-> 
#import <Foundation/NSObject.h>

@class CTPhoneNumber, NSArray, NSDate, NSDictionary, NSMutableArray, NSMutableDictionary, NSObject<CTMessageAddress, NSCopying>, NSString;
->
@class CTPhoneNumber, NSArray, NSDate, NSDictionary, NSMutableArray, NSMutableDictionary, NSObject<CTMessageAddress, NSCopying>, NSString;

NSObject<CTMessageAddress><NSCopying>
->
NSObject<CTMessageAddress,NSCopying>
```

For your question, you can delete the declaration or implementation about "XXUnknownSuperclass" or just delete "XXUnknownSuperclass" sometimes.

I prefer only declare the interfaces about current project. You can also search "iOS header" on github.com and download headers dumped and modified by others.

Commonly SBIconViewDelegate is implemented by SBIconController, you can check SBIconController's header file and hook related methods.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will try it out as soon as I can!